# как исправить проблему с хендлером который должен ловить пустые сообщения в aiogram python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Всем здрасьте, дело в том что я создал код в **answer.py**:

```
from aiogram import types
from data.config import cfg

from filters import IsPrivate

from keyboards.default import kb_menu
from loader import dp, bot, Dispatcher
from state.forward_FSM import FSMQuestion

devid = cfg['dev_id']
teh_chat_id = cfg['teh_chat_id']


async def client_answer(message: types.Message):
 try:
     if message.text == '✅Да':
         await message.answer(f'Чтобы задать вопрос сначала нажмите кнопку <b>✉ Задать вопрос</b>', reply_markup=kb_menu)
         await bot.send_message(teh_chat_id, f'✅ Заявка от <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b> успешно закрыта!')

     elif message.text == '❌Нет':
         await message.answer('Продолжите диалог с тех.поддержкой: ')
         await FSMQuestion.text.set()

 except Exception as e:
     await message.answer(f"Упс! <b>Ошибка!</b> Не переживайте, ошибка уже <b>отправлена<b> разработчику.",
                              parse_mode='HTML')
     await bot.send_message(devid, f"Случилась <b>ошибка</b> в чате <b>{message.chat.id}</b>\nСтатус ошибки: `{e}`",
                                parse_mode='HTML')

def register_handler_answer():
 dp.register_message_handler(client_answer, IsPrivate())
```

и у меня есть код в файле **other.py** который отлавливает пустые сообщения и отвечает на них, до создания файла **answer.py**  код из **other.py** работал:

```
from aiogram import types
from loader import dp, bot,




async def send_message(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer(f'Бот не видит что вы пишите, чтобы начать заново нажмите /start' )



def register_handler_other():
    dp.register_message_handler(send_message, content_types=['text'], chat_type='private', state=None)
```

если поставить в списке регистрации хендлеров файл **answer.py** выше файла **other.py** то **other.py** не работает, как это исправить?
Вот список регистрации хендлеров в файле **app.py**

```
    start.register_handler_start()
    buttons.register_handler_buttons()
    forward_FSM.register_handler_FSM()
    admin.register_handler_admin()
    registeradmins.register_handler_adminreg()
    register.register_handler_registration()
    answer.register_handler_answer()




    other.register_handler_other()
```

Остальные хендлеры работают кроме other.register_handler_other()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте декораторы вместо *register_message_handler*.

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_message(message: Message):
        await message.answer(f'Бот не видит что вы пишите, чтобы начать заново нажмите /start' )
```

Советую переписать таким образом весь код, таким образом вы сократите код и освободите себя от рутины ручной регистрации хандленов. Aiogram автоматически все зарегистрирует и ошибки пропадут.